# Unable to Close Fancybox iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, fancybox, impress.js

My issue is available at http://www.jeremiahbenes.com/#/portfolio by clicking on one of the tiles. I tested this in the latest release of Chrome for Mac and experienced the issue described below.

I have implemented fancybox, but when the iFrame appears, I am unable to close it. The "x" in the top-right corner appears to be unclickable. Here is what I have for my implementation:

```
<a data-fancybox-type="iframe" class="fancybox fancybox.iframe plink" href="http://gegarageenvy.com">
  <span>GE Garage Envy</span>
</a>
```

The code I have for Fancybox is:

```
<script type="text/rocketscript" data-rocketoptimized="true">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.fancybox').fancybox();
    }); 
</script>
```

Why does it not close?

(On another note, how can I set it to automatically take up 95% of available height and width? I tried using autosize, but that does not work).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a class in your body tag which is disabling pointer events, which is stopping you from being able to click anything inside that fancybox,

```
.impress-enabled {
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

If you remove this class from the body, then everything inside of fancybox become clickable.

Otherwise you can add,

```
pointer-events: auto !important;
```

to the CSS of .fancybox-wrap.

Comment: Please don't post anything as an answer until you actually have an answer; referring to your initial posting, which was nothing more than a comment.  You will trigger unnecessary flags creating work for the moderators.  It's really not a problem that the OP is "in the dark" until a real answer comes.  You also risk down-votes as people rarely come back to see your revisions. Looks good now though.

Comment: Alright, sorry for that, will remember that in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after googling a bit I found this solution. It's similar to that what @NZ Mikey said:

Add following CSS...

```
.fancybox-wrap {
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

The problem is a known one and can be found here:

- https://github.com/jmpressjs/jmpress.js/issues/85
- https://github.com/bartaz/impress.js/issues/172